# Using Javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I know this question has already been asked a few times, but I'm trying to use javascript with php. I have a file called parsing.php that parses through a xml feed and converts the metadata into JSON Object called "data". The parsing is done using ajax calls with JavaScript and JQuery.

```
<script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'fakeFeed.xml',
 dataType: 'xml',
 async: false,

success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
function getRandom(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function getThumbId(small) {
  var num = getRandom(15);
  if (num == 0) {
    num = 1;
  }
  if (num < 10) {
    num = '0' + num;
  }
  return num.toString();
}

var categories = new Array();  // Array for the categories
var category = {
  name : '',
  videos: []
}; 
var data1 = data;
var data = {
  categories: []
};

$(data1).find('item').each(function () { 
  var el = $(this);
  var categoryName = el.find('category').text();
  var p = categories.indexOf(categoryName);
  if( p == -1) {
    categories.push(categoryName);
    var category = {
      name: categoryName,
      videos: []
    }; 
    for (var j = 0; j<5; j++) {
      var video = {
        sources: [el.find('media\\:content, content').attr('url')],
        thumb : 'images\/thumbs\/thumb' + getThumbId() + '.jpg',
        title : el.find("title").text(),
        subtitle : el.find("description").text(),
        description: ""  
      }
      category.videos.push(video);
    }
    data.categories.push(category);
  }
});

window.data = JSON.stringify(data);
 <script>

 "<?php
   $dataVar = ?> <script type=text/javascript>window.data</script><?php;?>" 
 "<?php
   print_r($dataVar,true);
  ?>"
```

The only reason why I need to use javascript and php is because I want to use the "print_r()" function from php which allows me to return the information rather than just printing it to the screen, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. If anybody knows of other alternative or could give some advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already have one AJAX request, so you understand the concept of AJAX. You need to use AJAX to send the parsed data to the server. Alternatively, use `DOMDocument` to parse the XML server-side.

Comment: THis portion has errors: "<?php
   $dataVar = ?> <script type=text/javascript>window.data</script><?php;?>" 
 "<?php
   print_r($dataVar,true);
  ?>"

Comment: `async: false,` please no!

Comment: because PHP runs on the server and Javascript runs on the client. JS cannot **EVER** directly invoke a PHP function, or vice versa.

Comment: is there any way I can run this file without the php, and then send the "data" to a php file, and print it from there @MarcB

Comment: AJAX calls, as the others have mentioned.

Comment: bleh, personally i like to set my Ajax to json returns and return my php object as `echo(json_encode(array));` Then I have a nice JS object to work with on my success callback

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm sort of new to Ajax, so I'm not really sure about how to do this

Comment: @MarcB `JS cannot EVER directly invoke a PHP function ...` that statement is not entirely true in and of its own.

Comment: You know, JS can parse the XML just fine, too.

Comment: to add to Thomas' comment, if you return an xml object, you can use jQuery to make it an object `var bob = $(data);` and then parse through it like any other jQuery HTML Object. `bob.find('innerXMLchildTAG')`

Comment: @ThomasWeinert yes but i don't want all tags that the xml had

Comment: @SpYk3HH you said to set your Ajax to json returns and then return the php as echo(json_encode(array)), but with the code that I have right now, i can't really do that because my "array" is in javascript. correct??!!

Comment: No, the array I refer to is PHP side, you return it using `json_encode` and thus it `prints` as a JSON Object on the JS side. If you're sending an array to ur PHP via the ajax `data` attribute, then you need to understand expected data pattern, `[ { name: 'item1', value: 'val1' }, { name: 'item2', value: 'val2' } ]`

Comment: @SpYk3HH thanks for the help. I'm sending the array to my php side and then printing it from there. once i get it to the other side i can just call print-r() on data and it should be print like [ { name: 'item1', value: 'val1' }, { name: 'item2', value: 'val2' } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I believe you are trying to achieve, written in PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("fakeFeed.xml");

$data = ["categories"=>[]]; // may need to use array() instead of [] depending on PHP version
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) {
    $name = trim($item->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->textContent);
    if( !isset($data['categories'][$name])) {
        $cat = ["name"=>$name,"videos"=>[]]; // again, adjust if you're on an older version
        // I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve on this part.
        // you seem to be getting the same video five times...
        // revise your approach, comment if needed, and I can try to help
        // for now, "insert code here"
        $data['categories'][$name] = $cat;
    }
}
// we were using the name as a key for simplicity, now just take the values
$data['categories'] = array_values($data['categories']);
// done! $data now has your data.
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I was adding the videos there just as filler data. When I tried running this code i couldn't get anything to come up in the screen

Comment: actually i think it might be because of the arrays(). i'm going to try and change it and see if it does anything

Comment: $data = array("categories"= array()) and                           $cat = array("name"=>$name,"videos"=array()) is the right syntax for arrays. Sorry php is not really my forte. if so, I'm still not getting it to work.

Comment: Ah, I see, you haven't discovered the wonder of PHP 5.4 ;) Still, the rest should work. Do you have `display_errors` turned on?

Comment: haha yup. I'm still living in the dark ages when it comes to php. but I'm getting 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in parsing2.php on line 5 and syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' 
$dom->load("fakeFeed.xml"); // this is line5

Comment: Have you done `$data = array('categories'=>array())` and `$cat = array('name'=>$name,'videos'=>array())`?

Comment: wow that did it my good sir!! Two last questions: If I were to encode this in a way that I could print the final data as a json object i would just  do print_r(json_encode($data))? As for the video parts that I was putting the same video 5 times, i can just follow your logic in terms of syntax and that should do it right?

Comment: No, just `echo json_encode($data);`. Yes, you should be able to follow similar methods to the current code to get at the video data you need.

Comment: once again thank you so much for the help Niet. Sorry to bug you one last time. I ran into a little problem. one of the tag names on the xml feed is <media:content url="www.youtube.com"></media:content> i have tried doing the "getElementsByTagName('media:content')" but i have not succeeded . When I had JQuery i found the element by doing "find('media\\:content, content').attr('url')". is there any way possible to grab that element or am I in deep waters for lack of better term

Comment: You need [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php) for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use this instead of using document.log for JS:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "some_php.php",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data);
                })
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                        document.write(msg);
                    });
```

and the some_php.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: THanks for the comment @Alejandro but I can't get this to work. when I check the some_php.php I get a blank page.I put the ajax call that you suggested after the closing brackets of my ajax call...

Comment: Put the ajax inside a function and call it at the end of you original ajax call